# How do I run this Ignited datatable tutorial?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatable

[The printscreen of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcbWR.jpg)

I got this tutorial from this link:http://www.ahmed-samy.com/php-codeigniter-full-featrued-jquery-datatables-part-1/?replytocom=80#respond

So I followed the steps but no matter how much I retrace, I can't get this to run. I need help badly

Comment: you want to add datatable to your html table??

Comment: I already added a database and data as said in the tutorial (for checking if it works)
but I couldn't get through the error even if I followed all the steps in the tutorial

Comment: can u add line number 257 from core/common.php file??

Comment: Have you tried the tutorial?
I downloaded their source code to guide me in building my own but I can't make their source code run 

I disabled the debug just to see where the code stops...
It stops at where the gif runs but it just can't read the db and the data in it even if I matched all the things in the tutorial's specifications

Comment: I did fix that with this...
but the db still can't be read...

line 257:  $_config[0] =& $config;
line 258:                   return $_config[0];

Comment: what is d current error??

Comment: Just that db error on the screen

Comment: check the answer, first replace the code then create database. Its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the tutorial, and your error,

in `core/common.php` file
change

```
return $_config[0] =& $config;
```

to

```
$_config[0] =& $config;
return $_config[0];
```

Create a database called `hype_text`, then run the sql which is given in `step 1`, it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you but I'm already done with that...
The only remaining is that db error

Comment: create a db by name `hype_text` and run sql which is in tutorial.

Comment: I already did and it's "hype_news"  not hype_test (The name in source code of their config/database.php)

filled it with the necessary code found in the tutorial
I also did the reconfiguration of the autoload.php as well

Comment: Nope
Still the same db error
and I don't know what's wrong with the DB_driver.php

Comment: A Database Error Occurred

Unable to select the specified database: hype_news

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial_datatables\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 140

Comment: database name is wrong... there is some error in db name. did u create db `hype_news`??

Comment: never mind dude...
you're not really finding any alternatives...
just stop commenting...